# Entity Framework: Eager loading for properties of subclass type for TPT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading, eager

I use [Table per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) I have something like this

```
class A
{
    //some properties
}

class B : A
{
    //some properties        
}

class C : A
{
    //some properties  
    public virtual D D;      
}

class D
{
    //some properties
}

class E
{
    //some properties  
    public virtual A A;
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<E> Eis { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I want to perform eager loading for property D of class type C when I retrieve objects of type E. Something like this

```
DbContext.Eis.Include("A")/*But I'm not able also to add .Include("A.D")*/;
```

Is it possible to do eager loading in this case?

**UPDATE**

@Marty said it's impossible. Seems to me that I'm able only use lazy loading, correct? But I want to load objects forcibly, because I'm going to use objects after DbContext will be disposed. So how can I do this? Currently I use for-loop with access to each element for lazy loading.

Comment: How can you ask that, when the A class has no property D. If You'd be loading "C's", then it would work db.Set<C>.Include(p=>p.A)

Comment: I want to load all EntitiesContainsPropertyA

Comment: A isn't a property: it is a class, and all classes derived from it will already have the properties that are defined in class A, without needing to do an 'include'. An include is for bringing back the navigation properties, that are entity collections in their own right (which the properties defined in class A are not).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok I'm going update question

Comment: You cant do that that way, cause A - doesn't have a property D

Comment: @Marty, thank you. I know that A doesn't have the property D, I thought maybe it's possible to load by another way.

Comment: Yes, You can. db.Eis.SelectMany(p=>p.A).OfType<A>().Include(i=>i.D)